# How to use Swift generic enum's?

Tags: swift, generics, request

My question is pretty simple? How can you use generics in enum's?

i've got a protocol:

```
protocol Request {
   associatedType BackendModel = Codable
}

class FirstModel: Codable { }

class FirstRequest: Request {
   typealias BackendModel = Codable
}
```

Now i want to make an enum with a succes/failure for the request call. And the success should return my BackendModel. i thought something like this but it doesn't work.

```
enum Response<T: Codable> {
   case success(T)
   case failure(Error)
}
```

And then i would use it in a function completion

```
// This function is used in an extension of the Request protocol.
func doCallWithCompletion(completion: ((Response<T: BackendModel>) -> Void)?) {
     let model = FirstModel()
     completion(.success(model))
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a concrete type as generic parameter while declaring closure with enum:

```
extension Request {

    func doCallWith(completion:(Response<FirstModel>) -> ()) {
        let model = FirstModel()
        completion(.success(model))
    }

}
```